# Shibboleth SP clustering

Tags: devise, cluster-computing, shibboleth, service-provider

We are supporting a multi-tenant application. Most of the time, there is substantial load on our application. Our technology stack involves:

- Rails 3.2.13
- Ruby 1.9.3

Running on Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) with Passenger(3.0.11).

Related Gems:
devise (2.2.7)
oauth (0.4.7)
oauth2 (0.8.1)
omniauth (1.1.4)
omniauth-oauth (1.0.1)
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.3)
omniauth-shibboleth (1.0.8)

We have configured shibboleth2 to use the StorageService type="Memory". 
We have 2-3 application servers running at any point in time.
Off late, many of our clients have complained that they are unable to login via Shibboleth SSO. On debugging, what we observed is that, the issue is more frequently occurring on Chrome browser on Mac OS.
In the Browser Network window, we see that the user is not treated as logged in, even after successful authentication at IDP. If the user clicks the 'Sign in' link (which redirects to /users/auth/shibboleth), the system treats the user as logged in. This is very confusing for our clients.
Can you please help us understand where the issue might be? Is it at omniauth-shibboleth, devise or browser cookie's erratic behaviour? We are unable to conclude this issue.

Also, would you suggest to move the StorageService type="ODBC" instead of Memory since the Application servers (hence the SPs) are in auto-scale mode? If yes, I would need some documentation/tutorial for configuration of the ODBC StorageService.
When I gave it a try, the callback URL is not initiated at all - I am still wondering why has the omniauth_controller's callback provider method is not invoked at all.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.
I followed following steps:

1. Since we are using Postgres 9.3, install postgres ODBC libs:
   Steps to install postgres library & ODBC

rpm -ivh http://yum.postgresql.org/9.3/redhat/rhel-5.4-x86_64/pgdg-centos93-9.3-1.noarch.rpm

yum install postgresql93-odbc*

yum install -y postgresql-libs

ln -s /usr/lib64/libpq.so.5 /usr/lib64/libpq.so
ln -s /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/psqlodbc.so /usr/lib64/psqlodbc.so

2. Created database and tables:
   CREATE TABLE version (
   major int NOT NULL,
   minor int NOT NULL
   );
   INSERT INTO version VALUES (1,0);

CREATE TABLE strings (
    context varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    id      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    expires timestamp    NOT NULL,
    version smallint     NOT NULL,
    value   varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (context, id)
    );

CREATE TABLE texts (
    context varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    id      varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    expires timestamp    NOT NULL,
    version smallint     NOT NULL,
    value   text         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (context, id)
);

3. Modified shibboleth2.xml:

Then follow the steps on https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPODBCStorageService

4. Restart Apache and Shibd services.